# playing audio in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I wanna play an audio called "police.mp3" witch is located in Resources / raw by Click on PoliceClicked button
I used to watch some videos in youtube and really didnt find anything.
Im using this code right now

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FakeCaller;
using System.Numerics;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;

namespace FakeCaller
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private ISimpleAudioPlayer policePlayer;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Load audio files from Resources/raw folder
            policePlayer = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
            policePlayer.Load("android.resource://" + AppInfo.PackageName + "/raw/police.mp3");

        }

        private void PoliceClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            policePlayer.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

acctualy it doesnt have any errors but it cant find my audio file.
and im using this just for android